# Android streaming .wav audio file from server is not working

Tags: android, service, android-mediaplayer, wav

I have been trying to stream .wav file from server in the background. It works fine with .mp3 audio files. But when I try to play an .wav file, it is not playing. I implemented the audio player as a service.  The following is the code

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SoundService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

private static final String TAG = "MyService";
String url;
MediaPlayer mp;

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    Log.i("OnBind", "Inside OnBind");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");

    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("Stopping", "onDestroy");

    mp.stop();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i("Starting", "onStart");

    url = intent.getExtras().getString("url");
    Log.i("Starting2", "onStart2");
    try {
        mp.reset();
        Log.i("URLIS",""+url);
        mp.setDataSource(url);
        Log.i("Datasource", "datasource");
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        Log.i("preparedlistener", "PreparedListener");
        mp.prepareAsync();
        Log.i("prepareasync", "prepareAsync");
    } catch(Exception e){}
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    Log.i("onprepared", "insideprepared");
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

}

The service is called from the onactivityresult in mainActivity passing the url of audio file in intent.

```
public void onResponse(String response) {

            Log.i("Myresponse",""+response);

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SoundService.class);
            i.putExtra("url",response);
            startService(i);
            Log.i("Myresponse",""+response);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

My log cat when streaming .wav file is as follows

```
10-02 15:00:03.527 27677-27734/com.example.gkrish.momdadme E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
10-02 15:00:03.534 27677-27677/com.example.gkrish.momdadme E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code u have written is correct and most probably because of the response

Comment: The problem is solved, it was due to the error in the server.